# How to display results of a sql query on screen

Tags: android

I am trying to write a simple app just to display on screen the results on a sql query.

```
public class ContactLookup extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                null, null, null, null
                );
    }
}
```

How exactly do I print the results of the cursor?  Everything I find goes into to way more detail then I need at the moment...  I just want to know how to get that variable printed on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have something that shows text (or whatever you get from your DB). Most likely this will be a simple [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) (you can do this in the XML-Layout or in Java-Code).

If you declared your TextView in the XML-Layout, then you'll need to [find the `TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) in order to set it's text.

After that, you'll want to [move the Cursor to the first set of data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29) in it so you can read your results from it.

After that, you can simply use the [Cursor's getXX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)-methods to get your values form the result-set.

Comment: Thanks Lukas,  you have pointed me in the correct direction... I was able to get all the contact names printed on the screen. I appreciate the help.